# Java -Out of Memory when passing file from UI to webService

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, out-of-memory

Hello all I have a WS that works fine that needs to be used for another application.  This application uploads 20mb .CSV files.  If I alter the file to say 10mb the files makes it to the WS and continues processing.  If I leave the file intact at 20mb+ while streaming to the WS, I get a TOMCAT out of memory in logs before it even goes into the that java class :

Any recommendations on this?

```
INFO   | jvm 2     | java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
STATUS | wrapper   | Filter trigger matched.  Restarting JVM.
```

Pretty much doing a ajax call with JS to a rest service:

JS:

```
var params={};
    params.upldFile= $("#inputUploadFile").val());

var options = {
         url: 'WS/TEMP',
         data: params,
         dataType:"text",
         success:function(successJson) 

     };

    $('#TEST').ajaxForm(options);
     $('#TEST').ajaxSubmit(options);
```

JAVA

```
@Path("TEMP")
@POST
@Produces({  "application/json" })
@Consumes("multipart/form-data)
public Response test(
  @FormDataParam("inputUploadFile") InputStream iStream,
  @FormDataParam("inputUploadFile") FormDataContentDisposition detailFile) {

  //not making it here
  }
```

Comment: How big is the file ?

Comment: For starters, you could increase the heap allocated to Tomcat JVM : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: its 20mb+....yeah I told the architect we need to increase memory...but they want a justification for the memory increase...I was just seeing if there is another way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `byte[]` instead of `InputStream`. which seemed to remedy the problem with 20mb files, as our QA server only has 124 mb.

Answer (score 0):

The “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space” is thrown whenever the leaked memory fills all of the available memory in heap region and garbage collection is not able to clean it.

Try out to increase the availability of such a resource. When your application does not have enough Java heap space memory to run properly, fixing it is as easy as altering your JVM launch configuration and adding (or increasing if present) the following:

-Xmx1024m

Or you can go ahead and try out [Plumbr](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space) for free. When we find the cause for the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError you will see the exact location of the problem along with solution guidelines.